# Predicting Missing Words in a sentence - Natural Language Processing Model

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, nlp, predict

I have the sentence below :

```
I want to ____ the car because it is cheap.
```

I want to predict the missing word ,using an NLP model. What NLP model shall I use? Thanks.

Answer (score 23):

## TL;DR

Try this out: https://github.com/huggingface/pytorch-pretrained-BERT

First you have to set it up, properly with

```
pip install -U pytorch-pretrained-bert
```

Then you can use the "masked language model" from the BERT algorithm, e.g.

```
import torch
from pytorch_pretrained_bert import BertTokenizer, BertModel, BertForMaskedLM

# OPTIONAL: if you want to have more information on what's happening, activate the logger as follows
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Load pre-trained model tokenizer (vocabulary)
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

text = '[CLS] I want to [MASK] the car because it is cheap . [SEP]'
tokenized_text = tokenizer.tokenize(text)
indexed_tokens = tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(tokenized_text)

# Create the segments tensors.
segments_ids = [0] * len(tokenized_text)

# Convert inputs to PyTorch tensors
tokens_tensor = torch.tensor([indexed_tokens])
segments_tensors = torch.tensor([segments_ids])

# Load pre-trained model (weights)
model = BertForMaskedLM.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
model.eval()

# Predict all tokens
with torch.no_grad():
    predictions = model(tokens_tensor, segments_tensors)

masked_index = tokenized_text.index("[MASK]")
    
predicted_index = torch.argmax(predictions[0, masked_index]).item()
predicted_token = tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens([predicted_index])[0]

print(predicted_token)
```

[out]:

```
buy
```

## In Long

To truly understand why you need the `[CLS]`, `[MASK]` and segment tensors, please do read the paper carefully, https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.04805

And if you're lazy, you can read this nice blogpost from Lilian Weng, https://lilianweng.github.io/lil-log/2019/01/31/generalized-language-models.html

Other than BERT, there are a lot of other models that can perform the task of filling in the blank. Do look at the other models in the `pytorch-pretrained-BERT` repository, but more importantly dive deeper into the task of "Language Modeling", i.e. the task of predicting the next word given a history.

Comment: Straight forward answer but you forgot to create the `masked_index` leading to an error near the end. I am assuming the `masked_index` is just the index of the `[MASK]`?

Comment: Masking in BERT is not padding (that usually happens at the start/end of the sequence) =) Read the BERT paper for more information.

Comment: Please add the following code   ``` masked_index = tokenized_text.index('[MASK]') ```

Comment: Another correction: Since you have a 3d tensor, you should actually do: "predicted_index = torch.argmax(predictions[0][0][masked_index]).item()" Also, consider @Biranchi comment. All working this way!

Comment: The new version of hugginface library is called `transformers` so instead of installing `pytorch-uncased-bert` one could do `pip install transformers` to get the latest version. The second import line becomes `from transformers import ....`

Answer (score 3):

There are numerous models you might be able to use. But I think the most recently being used model for such sequence learning problems, are bidirectional RNNs( like Bidirectional LSTM), you can get a hint from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_recurrent_neural_networks)

But be advised, Bidirectional RNNs are very expensive to train. Depending on your problem to solve, I highly advice to use some pre-trained model.
Good luck!