# Using Elmo models to predict the masked word in a sentence

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, allennlp, elmo

I have a homework which requires me to build an algorithm that can guess a missing word from a sentence. For example, when the input sentence is : " I took my **** for a walk this morning" , I want the output to guess the missing word(dog). My assignment requires me to train my own model from scratch. I built my corpus which has about 500.000 sentences. I cleaned the corpus. It is all lower-case and every sentence is seperated with a new line (\n) character. I also have vocabulary.txt file which lists all the unique words in descending order in frequency. The vocabulary file starts with the first 3 line 'S', '/S' and 'UNK' (these 3 tokens are surrounded with <> in vocabulary.txt but using <> in this website hides the characters between them for some reason) . I also have a small set of sentences with one missing word in every sentence which is denoted with [MASK], one sentence per line.

I followed the instructions in the https://github.com/allenai/bilm-tf ,which provides steps to train your own model from scratch using Elmo.

After gathering the data.txt and vocabulary file, I used the

```
python bin/train_elmo.py --train_prefix= <path to training folder> --vocab_file <path to vocab file> --save_dir <path where models will be checkpointed>`
```

and trained my corpus with tensorflow and CUDA enabled gpu.

After the training is finished, I used the following command:

```
python bin/dump_weights.py --save_dir /output_path/to/checkpoint --outfile/output_path/to/weights.hdf5
```

Which gave me the weights.hdf5 and options.json files. The only warning I received while training my model is :

```
WARNING : Error encountered when serializing lstm_output_embeddings.Type is unsupported, or the types of the items don't match field type in CollectionDef. 'list' object has no attribute 'name'
```

which was mentioned in the AllenAI repo as harmless. So it is safe to assume that the model training phase is finished correctly. My problem is, I have no idea what to do after this point. In this stackOverflow link [Predicting Missing Words in a sentence - Natural Language Processing Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54978443/predicting-missing-words-in-a-sentence-natural-language-processing-model), the answer states that the following code can be used to predict the missing word:

```
import torch
from pytorch_pretrained_bert import BertTokenizer, BertModel,BertForMaskedLM

# OPTIONAL: if you want to have more information on what's happening,activate the logger as follows
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Load pre-trained model tokenizer (vocabulary)
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

text = '[CLS] I want to [MASK] the car because it is cheap . [SEP]'
tokenized_text = tokenizer.tokenize(text)
indexed_tokens = tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(tokenized_text)

# Create the segments tensors.
segments_ids = [0] * len(tokenized_text)

# Convert inputs to PyTorch tensors
tokens_tensor = torch.tensor([indexed_tokens])
segments_tensors = torch.tensor([segments_ids])

# Load pre-trained model (weights)
model = BertForMaskedLM.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
model.eval()

# Predict all tokens
with torch.no_grad():
predictions = model(tokens_tensor, segments_tensors)

predicted_index = torch.argmax(predictions[0, masked_index]).item()
predicted_token = tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens([predicted_index])[0]

print(predicted_token)
```

Unfortunately, the code above is for Bert models. My assignment requires me to use Elmo models. I tried to find a library similiar to **pytorch_pretrained_bert** for Elmo but I couldn't find anything. What can I do to predict the masked words using my Elmo model?

Thanks.

Comment: Although they're both from sesame streets, Elmo works differently from Bert. Understand the model and why `[CLS]` and `[MASK]` exists from Bert and know how elmo is created. http://jalammar.github.io/illustrated-bert/

Comment: I am aware that they are different. I mentioned the code about Bert just to better explain what I was trying to do with my Elmo model. Since Elmo also pays attention to context, it should be well suited for my assignment.